# Second coroutine is never executed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two coroutines inside another one, it's supposed that both inner coroutines are going to execute asynchronously, but this doesn't happened. The second one waits until the first finish.
This is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     var flag = false
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

          runBlocking {
                launch {
                    printOne()
                }
                launch {
                    printTwo()
                }
          }
    }

    suspend fun printOne() {
         while (flag == false)
             Log.e("log", "111111")
    }

    suspend fun printTwo() {
         Log.e("log", "222222")
         Log.e("log", "222222")
         Log.e("log", "222222")
         Log.e("log", "222222")
         flag = true
   }
}
```

I assumed that the code inside the first `launch{}` would execute in a thread separately from the code in the second `launch{}` as well as any other corutine. But it keeps looping for ever inside the first `launch{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `Log.e` a suspend function? If not, then your first coroutine never calls another suspend function, and never explicitly yields, so it never gives other coroutines a chance to run on the same thread.

The call to runBlocking is using a default dispatcher that uses only one thread, so there's no thread available to run the second coroutine.

You could fix this by explicitly yielding after every loop iteration:

```
suspend fun printOne() {
    while (flag == false) {
        Log.e("log", "111111")
        yield() // <-- give other coroutines a turn
    }
}
```

If you try to fix the problem by using a different dispatcher (like `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)`), you may notice another problem...

The `flag` variable is not volatile. Changes to the variable made by a coroutine running in one thread might not be seen by  cooroutines in a different thread for a long time, if ever. You could fix this by annotating the property as [volatile](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/):

```
@Volatile
var flag = false
```

Comment: just FYI, no, `Log.e` is not `suspend`

Comment: it's supposed that the default dispatcher uses one thread by core and at least two, so I should be using two threads instead of one, or at least I read so.

Comment: @Danstern I see what you mean. The documentation for [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) does indeed say it always uses at least two threads. I'm no longer sure what's causing the resource starvation.

Answer (score 0):

**Coroutines are not threads**. You can set them to run in different threads if you want, using *Dispatchers*, but if not, you have to let execution time for other coroutines in the same thread with [yield()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) or [delay(Long)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `runBlocking`. Replace it for `lifecycleScope.launch`.

The Android library for activities/fragment added a coroutine launcher tied to the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get your answer with this simple example

```
suspend fun printOne() {
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
    println( "111111")
        delay(200)
}

suspend fun printTwo() {
    println( "222222")
        delay(100)
    println( "222222")
        delay(100)
    println( "222222")
        delay(100)
    println( "222222")
        delay(100)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).